# Intellij with run target as Docker randomizing ports

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

I am using intellij using the Run Targets configuration for deploying my build inside a docker container. The run target is based on a docker-compose file I provided.
My application is running on port 8080. The problem is that on each run, Intellij is assigning a random port from the host to the application port 8080.

I dont want Intellij to randomize port on each run. I explicitly mentioned in my docker-compose file to map 8080:8080. But still Intellij overrides it and assigns a random port. I also tried to run the application on different port but still no use.

Any one could help?

[image]

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with your run configuration?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

after adding the `ports: "8080:8080"` to the docker service config, make sure in the IntelliJ IDE docker run configuration you do **not** have the randomize ports option set.  See below:

[image]